# Parsing SQL containing semicolon (in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I coded a SQL parser that load data from a MySQL dump. The problem is that some SQL statements contain semicolon themselves so my parser take it as EOL as I use

```
$sqlRows = explode(';', $sqlFile);
```

to parse the dump file.

Any suggestion on how to manage this? I'm stuck :S

**edit:**

Sorry I forgot to say that the problem is that when PHP writes data to DB from the dump file, it returns me an error when it read the sentence that contain the semicolon.

I know it's not a full parser, it just read line by line. I'm new to this. I just need to "clone" the same DB (via dump file) to many, changing few data.

Comment: Your parsing algorithm is simply too simple.

Comment: _"Any suggestion on how to manage this?"_ How to manage **what** exactly? What doesn't work?

Comment: explode != parse. You need a real SQL parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$sqlRows=explode(";\n",$sqlFile);
```

So you will only get the ; that are at the end of lines. However it'll only work if your file is formatted with each statement finishing by a ; and each new statement beginning on a new line.

Comment: Thank you, it works. 
The file is formatted that way, 1 sentence per line endings with ";"

Comment: This will fail if you have data that itself contains this character sequence, e.g. if you have an "INSERT INTO foo VALUES('This is a text;\nThis is a text')". (The \n is not the escpace sequence in this case but would be the 'real' line feed character). Splitting / exploding simply is not powerfull enough. For this to work in every case you would actually have to design a real parser.

Comment: @Mirco Castellani : Don't forget to up the answer & validate it as good if it works for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the information Polygnome, anyway the file to parse is very simple so the method suggested by dweeves it's ok. 
Coding a real parser would be great, but I'm not in condition right now to write one, I just started programming.. I'll keep studyng and try to improve, thank you again

Comment: @dweeves I wanted to vote you up but it says I need 15 repu to do that but I just created the account